# Fatal error: Class 'wiImage' not found

Tags: php

I include WideImage library but resizing does not work; isntead it says 'Fatal error: Class 'wiImage' not found'

```
include('WideImageLib/lib/WideImage.php');

$img = wiImage::load($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

$res = $img->resize('50%');

imagejpeg($res, 'images/'.$_FILES['image']['name']);
```

Answer (score 3):

That would be because the class is called `WideImage` and the load call needs to be `WideImage::load`. You should probably read the [documentation](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/examples/basic/) again.

Answer (score 3):

And since you're working with an upload, you can use a shortcut:

`$img = WideImage::load('image')`

Also, all of your code (except the include statement) can be done as a one-liner:

`WideImage::load('image')->resize('50%')->saveToFile('images/' . $_FILES['image']['name']);`

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look at their [SourceForge page](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/), it looks like it should be `WideImage`

```
WideImage::load($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```